# Vuex store object getter returning different value when calling nested values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a Vuex store to store a user object. This is a getter for the user object

```
getters: {
    user: (state) => state,
    isAuthenticated: state => {
      console.log("user object", state);
      console.log("authorized", state.authorized);
      return state.authorized;
    }
},
```

However, when calling the getter this is what gets logged to the console.

[image]

As you can see the value for authorized changes whether the entire object is called or just the value itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because the console evaluates the object only when you expand it, and by that time `authorized` has been set to true. When logging objects, you aren't seeing a snapshot of the object at the moment it was logged.

In Chrome dev tools, hovering over the `i` symbol displays this tooltip:

[image: Screenshot]

Firefox dev tools does a similar thing.

It's best to set a breakpoint and inspect the object state in the debugger.

Comment: I think breakpoint is not even needed here if one is using Vue Dev Tools. Just clicking on different commits would display what has been changed :)

Comment: @GytisTG But that doesn't help in this situation where OP wants to inspect the state at the execution of a specific line of code.